# How to display a result in assembly

Tags: assembly

I am a beginner in learning assembly. I am using DOSBOX under Windows 7 64bit. I am wondering how can I display the value of a register in assembly. For example, I wrote the following code:

```
mov ax,20 ; ax will be 20
mov cx,10 ; cx will be 10
sub ax,cx ; ax will be 10 (ax-cx,20-10)
```

How can I display the content of the ax register (which supposed to be 10)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050433/display-results-of-an-asm-file

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the target OS or assembler, but if we assume DOS and NASM (shouldn't be hard to adapt to TASM/MASM):

```
org 100h
section .text

mov ax,123

mov byte [buffer+9],'$'     ; Insert string terminator
lea si,[buffer+9]

; create a string representation of the value in AX
mov bx,10
itoa:
    xor dx,dx       ; clear dx, since we'll divide dx:ax by bx
    div bx          ; ax = dx:ax / 10, dx = dx:ax % 10 
    add dl,'0'      ; add '0' to the remainder to get a character in the range '0'..'9'
    dec si
    mov [si],dl     ; store it in the buffer
    cmp ax,0
    jnz itoa

mov ah,9            ; print string
mov dx,si
int 21h

mov ax,4Ch          ; exit to DOS
int 21h

buffer: resb 10
```